# Why is strcmp returning false on the second run?

Tags: php, passwords, strcmp

So right now I'm making a simplistic login system. The client enters the form data and the php handles it by checking a text file that goes like so:

```
name
pass
name
pass
...so on
```

**The php I'm using to process this is:**

```
$name = $_REQUEST['name'];
$pass = $_REQUEST['pass'];
$validName = false;
$validPass = false;
$pos = 0;

$file_handle = fopen("database.txt", "r");

while (!feof($file_handle)) {

    $line = ltrim( fgets($file_handle), "\n" );

    if ($pos % 2 == 0 ) // Checks for names first on even rows
    {
        if( strcmp( $name, $line))// Normal checking returns correctly
            $validName = true;
    }
    else if( $validName === true ) // if odd, and a matching name check pass
    {
        if( !strcmp( $pass, $line) )// What's going on here? Why is it opposite?
        {
            $validPass = true;
        }
        break;
    }
    $pos++;
}
```

What's happening is that the first check `if( strcmp( $name, $line))` checking if there is a name in the data base that matches the input from the client.

This correctly returns true when the clients name matches a name in the data base. I check the password the ***EXACT*** same way, but some how it returns false when it's suppose to be true, and returns true when it's suppose to be false.

What's going on here?

*On a side note,* I'm only using `strcmp` because I couldn't get `$name === $line` to work.

Comment: `strcmp` returns `0` if the strings are equal. So `if (strcmp($name, $line))` will execute the next statement if `$name` and `$line` are not equal. It does not return true or false. See the [online doc for strcmp](http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_string_strcmp.asp)

Comment: @lurker Thanks, I just read that in the manual. But for some reason, in order for me to get the values to return correctly I now have to set them up like this : `if( !strcmp( $name, $line) == 0 )`. That makes no sense.

Comment: For equality, you should do `if(strcmp($name, $line) == 0)`, or `if ( !strcmp($name, $line) )`. But not a combination of both. If you don't like how the second one looks, use the first one. :)

Comment: @lurker That is what I originally thought .. I did the `(strcomp(a,b) == 0)` but that didn't get the correct results ..

Comment: @lurker solved it completely. There's was more fault on my side and that's why the comparisons weren't completely correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`strcmp()` returns an integer, not a boolean. In fact, it returns 0 if the strings match, which would evaluate to false in an if-statement. That is why it appears to have "reverse" behavior compared to a typical boolean function.

[See the documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strcmp.php).

Comment: thank you. I sort of saw that, but didn't fully realize it. Why does the first check work then is the real question now.

Comment: Read the [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strcmp.php) and compare the result with an integer, instead of trying to treat it as a boolean. e.g. `strcmp(...) < 0`

Comment: @Lemony-Andrew I couldn't say without seeing the values of each variable. Try `var_dump()`ing both of them and I'm sure you'll spot the difference. It may be extra whitespace that you can't see so ensure their lengths are the same. Also note that `strcmp()` is case-sensitive.

Comment: @Daniel Further to your answer, for completion sake it's worth mentioning it's case sensitive (along with that a case insensitive function exists), and the return values are integers and should be compared with integers (`strcmp(...) < 0` or `strcmp(...) === 0`).

Comment: @Daniel That's what I first used to compare the values but the value returned by `$_REQUEST` didn't have anything written about it with the var_dump() function. Also, I got something working now but still iffy about the subject.

Answer (score 0):

According to your code, it is not *exact* same way, but rather opposite:

```
    if( strcmp( $name, $line))
    if( !strcmp( $pass, $line))
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like there was a bigger problem then I thought.

There was 2 problems.

1, As Daniel explained perfectly

2, There was an extra character at the end of each line which threw off all comparisons. So to fix this I deleted the end of the line and now everything's working.

```
while ( !feof($file_handle) ) 
{

    $line = ltrim( fgets($file_handle) );
    $line = substr($line, 0, -1);/// This gets rid of the extra character

    if ( ($pos % 2) == 0 )
        $validName = ( $name === $line );// compares with ===, which is faster then strcmp
    else if( $validName )
    {
        $validPass = ( $pass === $line );
        break;
    }

    $pos++;
}fclose($file_handle);
```